# How to add line after float prompt?

Tags: python

I want a line space after this command:

```
float(input("Enter cost of meal:"))
```

This is for an assignment and I want to make sure I have proper formatting. I tried to put `/n/n` expecting the same results as my simpler commands but if it is that I don't know where to put it.

Comment: okay, my mom and me got it figured out nvm

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add line space means add **\n** at the end of the line.

```
float(input("Enter cost of meal:\n"))
```